# getjson does not work on production server but works on development machine

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following javascript that is using a selection changed to fill in a select list.

```
$(function () {
$("#bedrijvenauto").each(function () {
    var target = $(this);
    var dest = target.attr("data-autocomplete-destination");
    target.autocomplete({
        source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert('selected bedrijf');
            event.preventDefault();
            target.val(ui.item.label);
            $(dest).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#projectenauto").val("");
            alert('selected bedrijf');
            alert($('#BEDRIJF_ID').val());
            $.getJSON("/Project/GetListViaJson", { bedrijf: $('#BEDRIJF_ID').val() }, function (data) {
                alert('selected bedrijf');
                alert(data);
                $("#PROJECT_ID").empty();
                $("#PROJECT_ID").append(new Option("Maak een selectie", 0));
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    alert(data[i].value + ' ' + data[i].label);
                    $("#PROJECT_ID").append(new Option(data[i].label, data[i].value));
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            target.val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
    target.val($("#BEDRIJF_NAAM").val());
});
```

It works like a charm on my development pc. The alert are all coming out even the data is returning results. That is the difference with the development pc that does not give any results after the call to getJSON
I have the feeling I am missing a detail here.
I am not used to debugging on a webserver because I usually create GUI applications in WPF, and this is a student's work for his vacation and I now got to get it working without him being around anymore. Vacation is done :-(
But not for me.

Comment: What error message are you getting - check the brower console and the response in the Network tab

Comment: GET http://localhost/Project/GetListViaJson?bedrijf=7 404 (Not Found) It should be http://localhost/2Focus/Project/GetListViaJson?bedrijf=7

Comment: Before you `$.getJSON()` method, add `var url = '@Url.Action("GetListViaJson", "Project")';` so that your url's are properly generated and then use `$.getJSON(url, { ...` But it looks like you are using areas, and if its not in the same area, you may need `var url = '@Url.Action("GetListViaJson", "Project", new { area = "Focus" })';`

Comment: In the javascript code ? On the production machine everything runs under 2Focus whereas in development it does not

Comment: Yes, in the script - it can go right at the top.

Comment: I'll try ;-) if it works

Comment: now i get Materiaal/@Url.Action(%22GetListViaJson%22,%20%22Project%22)?bedrijf=19 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Whats `Materiaal`? Are you using areas in your app?

Comment: This is a MVC5 applications, Materiaal is a controller, Project is a Controller too.

Comment: Did you surround `@Url.Action()` in single quotes?

Comment: yes I did sourround with single quotes.

Comment: It generates the correct url for me (and generates what you showed when you exclude the quotes). The only other thing I can think of is that this is in an external js file. In which case add tthe `var url = ..` in the main view, or add it as a `data-` attribute of the element your handling

Comment: It is an external js file. I'll try adding it to the view as a global. Excellent support btw you should create an answer i can upvote and close

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works. I'll mark your answer if you provide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error indicated in your comments means the url your creating is incorrect. Always make use of the `@Url.Action()` method to ensure they are correctly generated. In your script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetListViaJson", "Project")';
$.getJSON(url, { bedrijf: $('#BEDRIJF_ID').val() }, function (data) {
  ....
}
```

or if this is an external script, then add the `var url = '@Url.Action(...)';` in the main view (razor code is not evaluated in external script files), or add it as a `data-` attribute to the element your handling

```
data-url = "@Url.Action(...)"
```

and get it again using `var url = $(someElement).data('url');`

Comment: So in your first block of code, you mean `$.getJSON(url, ...)` right? What if my url is a variable, should I split it on the `/` chars to feed it to `@Url.Action`?

Comment: @Pawamoy, Well spotted (now edited). Not sure what you mean by _my url is a variable_? How was it generated in the first place?

Comment: I am using Django, and I pass the url in the context of the template, as a variable called url: `$.getJSON("{{ url }}", function(...` I can assign it to a javascript variable before using it, if needed: `var my_url = "{{ url }}";`

Comment: @Pawamoy, I'm not familiar with Django, but I assume it would be giving you the correct relative url so i that case `@Url.Action()` would not be necessary

Comment: Well I'm generating the url myself, and I make it relative yes. Opening the console on firefox, I see that the request results in 404, but if I open the given url in another tab I am able to get the JSON results :/

Comment: Ok, the error comes from elsewhere. If I refresh the json page, sometimes it results in 404, sometimes in 200. I guess some things are computed dynamically and they should not. Thank you anyway :)